# I am trying to write a smart contract for a defy-Bank as a project. i can't figure out why hasTransfered() function not getting executed?

Tags: solidity, transactions, ethereum-wallet-dapp, addresses

Smart contract code:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

contract AddressWallets {

  // variables

  address owner;
  uint funds;
  bool transferFund;

  constructor() payable {
    owner == msg.sender;
    funds == msg.value;
    transferFund = false;
  }

  modifier onlyOwner{
    require(msg.sender == owner);
    _;
  }

  modifier fundTransfered{
    require(transferFund == true);
    _;
  }

  // list of wallet address

  address payable[] investorWallets; 

  // map through all the wallet addresses

  mapping(address => uint) investors;

  //Write a payable function called payInvestors which takes the parameters address and amount.

  function payInvestors(address payable wallet, uint amount) public {
    //Write logic in the function so that it can add new wallets to investorWallets and fill them with amounts of your choosing.
    investorWallets.push(wallet);
    investors[wallet] = amount;
  }

  function sendEthers() private fundTransfered {
    for( uint i = 0; i < investorWallets.length; i++) {
      investorWallets[i].transfer(investors[investorWallets[i]]);
    }
  } 

  // fund transfer trigger....

  function hasTransfered() public onlyOwner {
    transferFund = true;
    sendEthers();
  }

  function checkInvestors() public view returns (uint) {
    return investorWallets.length;
  } 

}
```

Comment: Always show the full code and error message. What are you executing? What error is being thrown?

Comment: @jashit you can use [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com) to share your full code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the constructor. Change your smart contract's contract into this:

```
constructor() payable {
    owner = msg.sender;
    funds = msg.value;
    transferFund = false;
}
```

With '==' symbol in your smart contract you're comparing the state variable's value with the global variables' value in solidity! On the contrary with '=' symbol you're assigning your state variable with the value of global variables.

**Note**: Remember to put a value into msg.value textbox in remix ide before deploy it! Otherwise the `hasTransfered()` function doesn't work because the smart contract's balance haven't a ETH to send to investors.